# Ubuntu wireless on lenovo 9s does not work with linksys driver or network

Tags: wireless

Will not detect or connect to Ubuntu on my netbook. Worked when xp was installed I am using a Lenovo 9s netbook. How can I and where can I get the drivers for my Lenovo to work with the linksys e1200  and network adapter m600

Comment: Version of Ubuntu you are running would be useful as well as the output from lspci

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Additional Drivers App](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers)